# Preferences API working with multiple ClassLoaders?

Tags: java, preferences

i am currently working with the Preferences API to save settings in a Vaadin application.
The application has 3 WebApps running on a Tomcat server.
As i have learned, the Tomcat server has a ClassLoader for every module running on it but it is all running in one Virtual Machine.

Can anybody explain to me why Java Preferences are working on multiple ClassLoaders? I cannot find any source for this and i didn't find anything by debugging.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working? And are you sure you want to use Preferences in a multi-user context? It is made more for desktop apps.

Comment: Not working as in, you start two applications, change some preferences in one and use get-Methods in the other application (running in a different JVM) and the changes won't show ([See Question 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/designfaq.html)). I have implemented a Wrapper class for saving user-Preferences which works fine.

Comment: Doesn't that Question 5 imply that the case you describe is not guaranteed to work? How would it? The different JVM don't talk to each-other, so how would they get notified of changes?

Comment: Maybe i have asked the question wrong: The question is not why it is not working on multiple JVMs but why it IS working with multiple ClassLoaders. Sorry i am not a native speaker.

Comment: I don't think it is safe to use with multiple ClassLoaders, either. What you seem to see is that the three versions of your class use the same in-memory Preferences object (because they are in the JVM). Not sure if that is a good thing. Tomcat is supposed to keep them isolated, and that appears to break down here. Preferences are not a database made for concurrent access.

Comment: So your opinion is, that it is unsafe and i should not use it?
Are there other simple options? Properties are not really a good alternative in my opinion, because the changes don't apply immediately.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33751/discussion-between-iliketocodenstuff-and-thilo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

You get a Preferences-object by calling:

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("test);
```

Preferences and PreferencesFactory is loaded by the Bootstrap ClassLoader and so it is the same for every module ([how ClassLoader work in Apache](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)) and because the object is created in the PreferencesFactory it is not created in a WebApp context.