# Saving all data in one location vs separating the different classes of data

Tags: java, database, preferences

I know this is a very subjective question but I will try to make it as specific as possible. The different classes of data are

- **Installation/Initialisation Data** (e.g. path of installation, serial number, server port, server address...)
- **Application/Purpose Data** (data which the application was built work with)
- **Configuration Data** (Settings like Colors, Certain Thresholds for calculations, Language....)

The Installation Data has to be saved in a ini-file because it should be editable without code or without accessing the database.

The Application Data is stored inside a database.

The question is now: Should I store the Configuration Data inside the same database (with Hibernate) and mix the different classes of data  **or**  save the config inside another file (works with [Preferences API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740925/preferences-api-working-with-multiple-classloaders)) and seperate the classes?

The project in question is a web-server running multiple modules which should all have access to the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple modules trying to access the same config file, it is better to put it in  a database (assuming it's transactional), so that we can update the file easily. If kept in the file system, you need to keep some mechanism to make read-write operations safe, like semaphores.

Comment: Hello, with Java Preferences it is save if the modules are running in the same JVM. I forgot to put this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740925/preferences-api-working-with-multiple-classloaders)